# Meaning of "faute de" in "faute de vivre en monarchie"

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, prépositions, locutions

> [Faute de vivre en monarchie, c'est aux familles régnantes d'autres
>   pays européens que les Français s'intéressent](http://www.leparisien.fr/politique/aimeriez-vous-que-la-france-ait-un-roi-ou-une-reine-21-07-2013-2997663.php).

I know that *faute de* means *for lack of*.

But I don't know how *faute de* can be translated in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

« Faute de » signifie pourtant bien « *for lack of* ». On pourrait traduire littéralement par « *for lack of living in a monarchy* » (qui est compréhensible même si ce n'est pas vraiment idiomatique). Je trouve la construction un peu bizarre ici, même si elle est grammaticalement correcte : j'aurais plutôt écrit « à défaut de vivre en monarchie », dont le sens est le même. Je crois que c'est parce que « faute de » appelle quelque chose qu'on peut avoir, ce qui n'est pas le cas de « vivre en monarchie ». Par exemple « faute de monarchie dans leur pays » m'aurait semblé parfaitement idiomatique.

Comment: Your French is so good. I only wish I'd one day speak it like you do...

Comment: I have to disagree with you. For me *“À défaut de”* is worse than *“faute de”*. *“À défaut de”* would imply a parallel between proposition: *“À défaut de vivre en monarchie, c’est d’une république que les Français doivent se contenter“*. And *“faute de”* doesn’t disturb me that much (at least not until I think a little bit about it), as I don’t mind understanding it as *“Parce qu’ils vivent pas”*.

Answer (score 3):

En ce qui concerne la traduction, je me crois pas qu'une solution *one-size-fits-all* fonctionnerait pour cette expression. Pourquoi pas "Not living under a monarchy" ou encore "Lacking a monarchy of their own"?